# Vector iterator not dereferencable. Priority queue of pairs.

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, priority-queue, dereference

So I have this code and after running it on visual studio I get the assertion error:
"...program files\microsoft visual studio\vc\include\vector
line: 70
Expression:Vector iterator not dereferencable"

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<queue>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
#define N 100003

pair<int, int> tab[N];
int a, b, x;
int odp[N];

int main(void)
{
priority_queue<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>, less<pair<int, int>> > Q;
cin>>a;
for(int i=1; i<=a; i++)
{
    cin>>tab[i].first>>tab[i].second;
    Q.push(tab[i]);
}
b=Q.top().second;
x=0;
Q.pop();

for(int i=0; i<a; i++)
{
        if(Q.top().second<b)
        {

            b=Q.top().second;
            Q.pop();
        }

        else if(Q.top().second>b)
        {
            x++;
            for(int j=1; j<=a; j++)
            {
                if(Q.top().first==tab[j].first)
                {
                    if(Q.top().second==tab[j].second)
                    {
                        odp[x]=j;
                    }
                }
            }
            Q.pop();
        }
}
cout<<x<<endl;

for(int i=1; i<=x; i++)
{
    cout<<odp[i]<<endl;
}
}
```

I have no idea what's goin on so if anyone could at least try to explain it to me I would be thankful.

Comment: Yeah, which line is 70 would be nice.  In general, you seem to be playing pretty fast and loose with ints and iterators, which are not the same thing.

Comment: Your if/else could have a fal thru condition, is that what you want?

Comment: The line 70 is in the `<vector>` header, not in his code. @user3672299: The more relevant question is, which line in your code calls the function that fails the assert.

Comment: You should check `a < N` before indexing `tab `with `i`

Comment: @user3672299 can you give a set of inputs that cause the problem? (preferably the smallest possible set you can find)

Comment: check your debugger stack when assertion triggered. It should be really easy to find out such bug under visual studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the inputs it's possible to call `Q.top()` when the queue is empty, which causes undefined behaviour (and could be the cause of your error).

In the initial loop you push `a` items into the queue. But then you `pop` one item, and loop `a` times. If all of the first `a-1` iterations pop, then the last iteration will check an empty queue.

For an example of this, input `1 1 2`. I.e. queue starts off with 1 item, then it is popped, and then the first (and only) iteration of the second loop checks `top()` of an empty queue.

To avoid this crash you can insert as the first line of the second loop:

```
if ( Q.empty() )
{
    std::cerr << "Fail - queue is empty\n";
    return 1;
}
```

(or throw and catch an exception etc.)

However perhaps this indicates that there is a logic error in your algorithm (I didn't try to grok the whole thing).

Note that you also should check `a < N` after `cin>>a;`, and it would be practical to also abort if the other `cin >>` line fails (as you have it, the algorithm will run through with all zero entries after an input failure).

If you still get the problem after adding these checks in, then post the updated code (including the checks) along with the input that generates the problem.

Comment: Also, `if(Q.top().first==tab[j].first) if(Q.top().second==tab[j].second)` can be replaced by `if ( Q.top() == tab[j] )`